# How can we differentiate between change and progress in the area of arts and natural sciences?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, art

I'm studying a branch of philosophy, which is theory of knowledge and I need to investigate this question. I think that in art, it is difficult to say there is progress... whereas natural sciences have. However, I'm still confusing...

Comment: The issues about [Progress](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/progress/) regarding knowledge and science are complex.

Comment: Having said that, we may consider historical data as empirical evidenze: [Smallpox vaccination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallpox_vaccine#History): from early attempts around 1700 to Jenner's paper to the Royal Society in April 1797: about 100 years. Polio vaccine time-line: from 1935 to 1960, 25 years. COVID-19 vaccine (expected) time-line: 2020.

Comment: Please, no more recycling of this under various one-time usernames.

Comment: Options : (1) no progress neither in arts nor in science ( relativism) (2) progress in science , not in arts ( Bachelard) (3) progress in both./ No progress in science : Heidegger possibly. / Progress in both : Hegel possibly.